# Strange behaviour in dojo filtering select

Tags: select, dojo, xpages, filtering

I have a problem in an xpages application where I use dojo filtering select. When I use type ahead and the result returned is restricted to one occurrence, I have the behavior shown below. How can I increase the height of the results listing. Is there any way to do this?

[image]

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do.  Try changing the CSS for the element.

Comment: It is a xpages component, so the css code is embedded in the component. How do I change the css in the result list of this component?

Comment: I think you need to provide some code, I use that control in several applications without an issue.

Comment: I'm not sure what the scroll bar at the bottom is, but it looks like maybe you haven't allowed enough space in the XPage to display options below the filtering select.

Comment: The space is sufficient, even suspecting it, I created the component in a blank xpage and the behavior was repeated.

What I noticed is that in IE compatibility mode 10 the list box with the result of type ahead works as expected. I am using version 7 compatibility mode.